# reg expression: get subdomain if existent

Tags: php, regex

The problem is the following - I want to get the subdomain out of a random url.

1. the subdomain might exist or not (www.domain.com or domain.com)
2. I want to get the full subdomain info

For instance, `www.somesite.com` would get me, using `preg_match`, an array with

```
[0] = www.somesite.com
[1] = www
```

Similarly, the domain `somesite.com` would get me:

```
[0] = somesite.com
```

(and no [1] would be indexed)

I was using the following reg_exp:

```
preg_match('/[www.]?([0-9A-Za-z-]+)'/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $array);
```

but for `www.somesite.com` it is getting me an array with

```
[0] = www.somesite.com
[1] = ww (the last w seems to be missing)
```

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What’s the subdomain of `example.co.uk`?

Comment: Your concept of "subdomain" is insufficiently specified. In `example.k12.city.md.us` or `www.news.example.co.uk` which part is "sub"? Hint: they are quite different.

Comment: Can we assume the input is a well formated url ?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't looked at your full regex but this part of the regex is sure a problem:

```
[www.]?
```

List of characters inside square brackets means only one is matched. This means either `w` or dot and that too optional because of `?`

It should have been:

```
(www\.)?
```

Comment: Note that `[1]` will always be indexed, but might be empty.

Comment: And it's not the last `w` which is missing; `[w.]?` matched the first `w` outside the capturing group, then the group captured everything up to just before the first dot.

Comment: You guys are totally right. It's () and not []. Still the issue remains with the best way to accomplish this because if www doesn't exist, then the \. after the www will not exist as well

Comment: @Consolas: Hope other answer solves your problem, if not just leave a comment here and I will take a stab.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'm checking out @svante answer, seems pretty straightforward. Will return with more info!

Answer (score 1):

A tip to get you on your way:

```
^(.+\.|)([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
```

should give you

```
[0] = www.somesite.com
[1] = www.
[2] = somesite.com
```

and

```
[0] = www.another.somesite.com
[1] = www.another.
[2] = somesite.com
```

and

```
[0] = somesite.com
[1] = 
[2] = somesite.com
```

Comment: Thanks a bung! Will try it!